# Pop Ups and Ads Being Displayed from the SO site

Tags: support, advertising

From the last day onward's while I click on any questions or some buttons or even in some specific blank spaces(I mean white space in the page) a lot adds are being displayed(in stackoverflow.com not on meta). Are we supporting adds in here or is it some kind of an issue from my side? I don't and I haven't added any new software's on my system think its an issue from my side as I don't have issues with any other sites.

Even when I tried to edit this question and clicked on the edit button, an adv pop up came up.The screenshot for it : [image: screenshot1]

While I was editing this question add was displayed in the edit screen itself.[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Screenshots help. Why not post one?

Comment: Does this happen when you use https?

Comment: I suspect these are ads injected by your ISP. We don't allow popup ads on Stack Overflow, so these are most likely not coming from us.

Comment: ok i will add the screenshots. Now too when I clicked on the add comment button I got another pop up.Will update with the screenshots.

Comment: Yeah, those are not ours. If you use https then your ISP should not be able to inject those ads - try that to confirm. Then complain to your ISP.

Comment: I bet the browsing history is even more interesting... :P

Comment: ok let me try it and update you.

Comment: @Oded: I used "https" and its working fine now.Thank you.So i guess the issue was with the ISP. I will lodge a complaint against this issue.

Comment: Have you installed a product called "superadremove"? Someone here complaining about that in conjunction with the URL shown in your screenshot. http://cybercrimecomplaints.com/content/adware-cant-remove

Comment: @MacroMan: I wont be much concerned about this if I am not much interested with SO and development. :P

Comment: @MartinSmith: its resolved now, I guess it was the problem with the ISP.

Comment: @Oded : I would also like to know whether an outdated java version would cause these kind of issues?

Comment: @KrishnaChandran - it is possible. If your JRE is not up to date, it might be vulnerable to a known issue. Doesn't mean it is that.

Comment: This is why https should be mandatory on the Internet. SE is really behind in support here.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge and confirmed by @Oded's comment Stack Overflow does not allow popup ads to be displayed on the website.

There are several possible reasons why that could happen to you:

- Your ISP is injecting ads (some do, its terribly annoying and if that turns out to be the case, you should switch if possible)
- You caught Adware on your PC (a kind of virus that does this)
- You access SO through some SCRAPER website that just emulated its design and plops ads on it - in such case use verify that they are abiding by the attribution requirement of the creative commons license, and, if not, report them appropiately via the "contact us" button on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am not aware of the first point, definitely 2nd and 3rd point is not the case. As I updated in the question, I have checked for malicious software and scanned with Avast and malware bytes. Maybe  should I try using some adware cleaner tool?

Comment: @KrishnaChandran It can only be one of those three. Either your PC is infected with something, your ISP is doing something, or you are on a false SO copy site. There are no popup ads on Stackoverflow, and I doubt there will ever be.

Comment: I bet its the second one.

Comment: @Criesto: Hi, I have used now spyware scanner,malware bytes and Avast and scanned everything. Nothing was there, also to make sure of the registry part used rouge killer too.

Comment: @KrishnaChandran Check your browser, maybe you have installed some browser extension. Check [this](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-adware-popup-ads/) out.

Comment: @Criesto: checked that one in the first place,its resolved now. i used "https" and everything is in place now.Thank you for helping me though. :)

Comment: You should accept this answer if it is the correct one. :)